# Recursive method sum of powers of 2 up to Xth power of 2

Tags: java, recursion, methods, command-line, return

I am having issues with my recursive method, that will return and print in main() the sum of the powers of 2 up to the Xth power of 2. X is a integer on the commandline argument.

So if my commandline argument is : "3"

*Output would be: 15

It should work like (1 + 2 + 4 + 2^3) As you can see there's "3" powers of 2

So whatever my number is that's how much powers of 2 will be added. I manage to work out in getting the power of 2^x, but I'm really confused on getting the sum of the powers of 2 to be added into my calculation :o

Also, I won't be utilizing Math.pow(), even if it would be easier x)

My code atm:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
      if (commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
         System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
      } 
      else {
         Integer number = new Integer(0); // initialize number
         try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
         } 
         catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // NumberFormatException
            System.out.println(exception + " is not a integer!");
            System.exit(1); // end program
         }

         Integer power = power2(number);
         System.out.println(power);

      }
   }

   public static Integer power2(Integer number){
      if (number == 0) {
         return 1;
      } 
      else {
         return 2 * power2(number - 1);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Hint: You're computing a sum but have not used a single `+`. So you'll need to add one somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all stick with the `int` rather that Integer as primitives are much faster and introduce less overhead.

Secondly, if you only need the powers of 2 I suggest using left shift operator, `<<` as it does just what you need:

```
public static int powerOf2Sum(int number) {
  if( number == 0 ) {
     return 1;
  }
  return (1 << number) + powerOf2Sum( number - 1 );
}
```

Note: be aware of integer overflow though, as when the power is great than 32 (the number of bits in int) it will roll over. In that case you would need a long, which is capable of representing integers up to 64's power.

Comment: Hi aljipa, I think I explained my problem incorrectly as your code didn't output correctly :o So for whatever my number is, so maybe 5. It will add 5 powers of 2 (1+2+4+8+16) + 2^5. :o

Comment: It should be `1 << number`.

Comment: Although, is there another way without the use of the left shift operator?

Comment: My bad, was a bit sleepy when answering, of course it should be 1 << number.

Answer (score 3):

Oh for goodness sake.

```
return ( 1 << ( number + 1 ) ) - 1;
```

And for those of you who like arbitrary precision,

```
return BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft( number + 1 ).subtract( BigInteger.ONE );
```

I think a closed form qualifies as trivially recursive.

Comment: I'm sorry :c! Your code sample those output correctly. Although I'm working with recursive methods and it should call upon itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
public static Integer power2(Integer number){
       return (number==0)?1:2*power2(number - 1);
}
public static Integer method1(Integer number){
    return (number==0)?1:power2(number)+method1(number-1);
}
```

And Call the `method1`

*Output:*

```
method1(3)  ==>  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning this instead:

```
int result = power5(number - 1);
return 2 * result + result;
```

This way, if you enter 1, you get 2^1 + 2^0 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static Integer power5(Integer number){
      if (number == 0) {
         return 1;
      } 
      else {
         return 2 * power5(number - 1)+ power5(number - 1);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I added a sample output to my question, as I may have caused confusion  :o

Answer (score 0):

I liked your question, and many of the other answers are good for an input of 30 or less; but I wanted something better

```
private static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.ONE
    .add(BigInteger.ONE);

private static BigInteger power2(int n) {
  BigInteger l = BigInteger.ONE;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    l = l.multiply(TWO);
  }
  if (n > 0) {
    return l.add(power2(n - 1));
  }
  return BigInteger.ONE;
}
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
  int number = 3;
  BigInteger result = power2(number);
  System.out.printf("power2(%d) = %s\n", number, result);
  while (true) {
    BigInteger MAX = new BigInteger(
        String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    result = power2(number);
    if (result.compareTo(MAX) > 0) {
      System.out.printf("power2(%d) = %s\n", number, result);
      break;
    }
    number++;
  }
  number = 256;
  result = power2(number);
  System.out.printf("power2(%d) = %s\n", number, result);
}
```

Outputs

```
power2(3) = 15
power2(31) = 4294967295
power2(256) = 231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279871
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
  if (commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
     System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
  } 
  else {
     Integer number = new Integer(0); // initialize number
     try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
     } 
     catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // NumberFormatException
        System.out.println(exception + " is not a integer!");
        System.exit(1); // end program
     }

     Integer power = power5(number);
     System.out.println(power);

  }
}

public static Integer power5(Integer number){
      Integer sum = 0;
if(number == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
Integer pow = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    pow *= 2;
}
sum = pow + power5(a--);
return sum;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Simba, as a recursion, I'm trying to loop without iterations/for loops :o